# Datalog for query

Tags: sql, database, datalog

I need some help with the following query:

With given relations:

```
hiker(HN, Name), mountain(MN, Height), climbed(HN, MN, Date).
```

**Q.**: Give safe Datalog rules(with negation if necessary) for the following queries:

(a) Find the names of hikers who climbed some mountains with `Height > 5000m`.

I wrote like this

```
hiker(Name): - moutain(MN, Height), climbed(HN, MN, Date), Height > 5000
```

But if I have to find names of hikers who climbed every mountain with Height > 5000m, I am having difficulty in understanding the difference between *some* and *every* in these two questions.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'some' question is easy to express in language like Datalog and SQL because you only have to find one mountain per hiker. It doesn't matter whether the hiker has hiked one, two, or more mountains. Datalog rules are perfect for this.

```
result(Name) :-
  hiker(H, Name),
  climbed(H, M, _),
  mountain(M, Height), Height > 5000.
```

The 'every' question is harder to answers because you need to now confirm that the hiker has climbed every single mountain, not just one of them.

Assuming a closed world database, the 'every' question can be translated in a double negation though, which is easy to express. You need to search for hikers for whom there does not exist a mountain > 5000m that they have not climbed.

I'll help you a little bit with the first part of this query, and then you can probably find the answer.

```
// this is just for convenience
high_mountain(M) :-
  mountain(M, Height),
  Height > 5000.

// there exists a mountain hiker H has not climbed.
some_not_climbed(H) :-
  hiker(H, _),
  high_mountain(M),
  !climbed(H, M).

// for hiker H there is no mountain that he has not climbed.
result(H) :-
  hiker(H, _),
  ...
```

Comment: mbravenboer: will it be like:-                                                             result(H) :-
hiker(H,_),                                                                                                      ! some_not_climbed(H)                                                                                  ?

Comment: Yes, sorry if it was too easy ;).

Comment: Hello Martin, I had another question... it wud be grt if you cud help me
The 3 relations ( edge(X,Y), Red(X,Y), Blue(X,Y) ) are considered a graph whose relations can be colored red/blue.

a) find the pairs of nodes X and Y where there is path (a sequence of linked edges) from X to Y ? Acc to me I think the ans should be path(X,Y) :- edge(X,Z) , edge(Z,Y) is it correct ?
b) Find the pairs of nodes X and Y where there is path (a sequence of linked edges) of even length from X to Y with alternating red and blue colors. How can I modify the ans to first part to get the ans for 2nd part ?

Comment: See my comment on the separate SO question you created for this.

Comment: @MartinBravenboer what datalog implementation are you using? Mine chokes on the supplied code. For example, it seems unhappy with "Height > 5000" in high_mountain/1.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say  we have 3 mountains that their height is greater than 5000 (names: M1, M2, M3).

A hiker named **X** has climbed 5 mountains (M1, M20, M30, M40, M50) and only one of those mountain's height is over 5000 (M1).
This hiker name should appear in your list for the first question because he has climbed 'some' mountains > 5000.

However, this hiker has **NOT** climbed all mountains that are higher than 5000 (he has not climbed M2 and M3), so his name should not appear in the second list.

Comment: Thanks.I understood your point. my doubt is how do we write it in datalog rules as per relation given in question. Lets say for names who went on all moutains with height > 5000 I wrote datalog like this: hiker(Name): - moutain(MN, Height), climbed(HN, MN, Date), Height > 5000. Is it right and how will it be different in case of some mountains with height >5000?